# Ruby before_validation triggers infinite loop of call back

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, callback

Product Model has an attribute_1. If recalculation is required for attribute_1 then before_validation will call. It giving `SystemStackError: stack level too deep` because  `self.save!` triggers the `before_validation`. How to stop infinite loop of call back.

```
before_validation :method_1, :if => :recalculation_required_attribute
```

I am using optimistic locking using `lock_version`. 'update_all' will not increase the `lock_version`. So I am using `save!`. It is calling the infinite look of call back.

```
def method_1
    ####
    ####
    if self.lock_version == Product.find(self.id).lock_version
       Product.where(:id => self.id).update_all(attributes)
       self.attributes = attributes
       self.save!
    end
end
```

Comment: You don't need to save this record, it will be saved anyway.

Comment: @MarekLipka Lipka I am using optimistic locking using lock_version. 'update_all' will not increase the lock_version. So I am using save!. It is calling the infinite look of call back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `self.save!` there: you are already inside the transaction, so just do whatever you want to do and let Rails save the record once you are done.

Sidenotes:

- `Product.where(:id => self.id).update_all(attributes)` probably could be rewritten as `products.update_all(attributes)` (having the association `this_model has_many :products`
- `self.attributes = attributes` is redundant unless `attributes` is an instance method.

Comment: I am using optimistic locking using lock_version. 'update_all' will not increase the lock_version. So I am using save!. It is calling the infinite look of call back.

Comment: @geeks think about it. You are in transaction, it's waiting till `before_validation` is done to save the record. In `before_validation` you do `save!` which runs `before_validation` again, which runs `save!` which runs `before_validation` which... I hope you get my point

Comment: Yes, you are correct, Can you suggest how to run, if before_validation only one time?

Comment: @geeks if you try to increment the `lock_version` just go with `self.lock_version = lock_version +1` or whatever the new iteration of `lock_version` should result in

Comment: `lock_version` is auto-increment, if I do it through the `update_all`, optimistic locking will not work.

Comment: @geeks I answered your initial question. If you have new question, consider accepting this one and create a new question about handling `lock_version`

Comment: Could you check new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52624818/ruby-how-to-handle-optimistic-locking-using-update-allattributes