# Ruby: Will optimistic locking work using update_all?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, locking

I am trying to implement the Optimistic Locking for Race Condition. For that, I added an extra column `lock_version` in the Product: Model through migration.

```
#Product: Model's new field:
    #  attribute_1
    #  lock_version                       :integer(4)      default(0), not null
before_validation :method_1, :if => :recalculation_required_attribute

def method_1
    ####
    ####
    if self.lock_version == Product.find(self.id).lock_version
       attributes["lock_version"] += 1
       attributes["updated_at"] = Time.now
       Product.where(:id => self.id).update_all(attributes)
       self.attributes = attributes
    end
end
```

Product Model has an `attribute_1`. If recalculation is required for `attribute_1` then `before_validation: method_1` will call.

I am using optimistic locking using `lock_version`.  However, `update_all` will not increase the `lock_version` and can't `self.save!` because it will 
trigger the `before_validation: method1` for infinite times.

If I do like following will optimistic locking work using update_all?

```
attributes["lock_version"] = 1 +1
attributes["updated_at"] = Time.now
Product.where(:id => self.id).update_all(attributes)
```

You can check more information on [lock_version](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Optimistic.html)

Comment: There's a lot going on here, I'd suggest you try to break your question up into individual problems. To start, if `method_1` is being called in `before_validate`, I'd remove the save and just set the attributes. In the course of a normal save, Rails / ActiveRecord will call this method and then call save; you don't need to tell it to save (and, as you noticed, doing so will result in an infinite loop).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby before\_validation triggers infinite loop of call back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52624048/ruby-before-validation-triggers-infinite-loop-of-call-back)